# Is it possible to use pointers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I think Ruby is interpreted to C. If so, how can I use the concept of pointers and other features that are parts of C environment?
How can we utilize the power of C with the simplicity of Ruby?

Comment: If you want to call a C library from Ruby, try [ffi](https://github.com/ffi/ffi)

Comment: What do you mean by power?  What does using pointers in Ruby give you, other than pointers in Ruby?

Comment: Ruby is not interpreted to C, the Ruby interpreter is written in C.

Comment: @Michael: to be precise, *a* Ruby interpreter is written in C.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Ruby, (almost) every variable is in fact a reference/pointer to an object, e.g.

```
a = [0, 1, 23]
b = a
a << 42
p b
```

will give `[0, 1, 23, 42]` because `a` and `b` are pointing to the same object.

So in fact, you are using pointers all the time.

If you want to do pointer arithmetic as in C, this is not possible with Ruby.

Comment: Not for Integer objects... `a = 1; b = a; b += 1; p a;` outputs 1

Comment: @LeonardoRaele: integers are special, yes. But still, your `a` is a reference. It's just that you cannot modify the integer objects in-place.

Comment: The rule does not apply to basic types, all language constants must be assigned by copy otherwise while doing a = 1 you're giving to the variable "a" the possibility to override the constant 1

Comment: very interesting looking at this coming from C

Comment: Integers are not so special. `b += 1` in fact is `b = b + 1`, where `b + 1` results in a new object that is assigned to `b`. The value of `a` stays, because it's a different object now.

Comment: @D-side: Yes, true. But they are special because their value is equivalent to their object id. You cannot have two different integer  (Fixnum) objects with the same value `42`. Hence, you cannot modify an integer object.

Comment: You can do pretty much the same with your own value class, if you so desire. Just don't put in any methods that mutate the object. While technically there will still be ways to mutate it, but they'd relate to reflection and other ways of cheating :P

Answer (score 3):

The "power of C and simplicity of Ruby" can be had through `FFI`, which is a much better interface than `Win32API` or `DL`.

Using `FFI` you can handle pointers from C.

Here are two examples that should get you started:

1. [How to call a C function from a DLL that returns a pointer to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14182535/181638)
2. [How to call a Win32 function from within Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14182709/181638)