# How to assign a pointer to a variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby, just wondering if its possible to assign a reference to a hash-key to a variable?

```
a = {
  foo: 1
}
b = a[:foo] // I don't want assign the value
b = 2
puts a
```

Instead of assigning the value, is there a way to assign a reference? It just that I don't want to keep writing `a[:foo]`, instead anytime `b` changes, I want to reflect it on `a[:foo]`. Perhaps a macro that simply replaces the text, wherever I write `ACCESS_FOO` it will replace with `a[:foo]`.

I apologize if this is asked before. Anytime I search for pointers `C` language pops up.

Comment: "Anytime I search for pointers C language pops up." Did you try explicitly including `ruby` in your search terms?

Comment: When I tried putting `ruby pointer` into a search engine, the first result I got was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208768/is-it-possible-to-use-pointers-in-ruby. Does it help?

Comment: `Did you try explicitly including ruby in your search terms?` Oh wow! why did not I think of that?! You solved all my problems. Thank you so much!! How could I ever repay you?!

Comment: No, you can assign the whole object/array as a reference to a variable, but I am wondering if there is a way to assign a reference to a specific hash-key. So that when I change the variable it will be reflected on the hash.

Comment: Ruby doesn’t have the concept of pointers. The only thing that comes close is assigning a _mutable_ object to both `b` and `a[:foo]` (string, array, or custom class) which could then be altered using method calls, e.g. `b.replace(…)`

Comment: You could define a method if the hash were initiated inside the method or if your hash were either an instance variable or a global variable, but I'm not sure I understand the goal.  How is it better to "write  ACCESS_FOO" then it is simply "writing a[:foo]"?  Its more characters and doesn't communicate as clearly what's happening.  I'm sure I must be missing something.

Comment: @michael imagine writing a[:bar][:something][:else]...[:foo]

Comment: At that point, you should encapsulate it in an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby every variable is just a pointer/reference to an instance, there isn't anything else.

```rb
a = { foo: "Hello" }
b = a[:foo]
b.gsub!('e', 'a')
puts a.inspect
# => { foo: "Hallo" }
```

So in your example `b` is not assigned a copy of "Hello", it really is a reference to the same instance stored in the hash.

When you assign to a variable though, you are replacing the reference/pointer stored in the variable with something else.

What you seem to try to do is go one level deeper: You want to have a pointer to a reference (kind of a `P**` in C, I guess). In Ruby you can solve this with any kind of additional object which can store your value. How about an array?

```rb
a = { foo: [1] }
b = a[:foo]
b[0] = 2
puts a.inspect
# => { foo: [2] }
```

Comment: You can also write a wrapper object which delegates to the integer and overrides `#=`, but probably don't.

Comment: Ah, I see, so in order to keep a reference, I will have to use an array or object. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
There are no pointers in Ruby, the variable only hold a reference.
https://robertheaton.com/2014/07/22/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/

But you can implement your own method. probably using [`eval()`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/eval)

Comment: The boxes analogy doesn’t seem to fit. You can assign an object to multiple variables, but how could you put the same thing into multiple boxes? You can’t. Better think of the variables as labels you attach to the objects.

Comment: Ok, so can I say `b` refers to `a[:foo]`? Not even with text replacing macros that `C` language has?

Comment: This should be a comment as you are merely directing the OP to a link. I don't understand what "implementing your own method" means after you have said Ruby doesn't have pointers.